# Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

The following code, which worked well right up until I upgraded to windows 8.1 / Internet Explorer 11, is now throwing an error:  "Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference"

```
var SelectedData = window.external.menuArguments.document.selection.createRange().text;
```

Is there a fix / work around for this?

*** Question updated below with newer code that is still not working ....

```
<html><head><title>-</title><script type="text/JScript">
function Launch()
{
var TheSelection = document.getSelection();
if(TheSelection != null)
{

.... do  a bunch of stuff

}
window.close();
}
</script></head><body onload="Launch();" </body></html>
```

I have also tried
window.getselection;
window.getselection();
window.getselection().tostring();

none of these seem to work ...???

Comment: Has it occurred to you that you might be trying to call createRange on a null or undefined reference?

Comment: yes, but that is not the problem - please see notes from awiebe below for more information

Comment: While it may not be the problem, you should have mentioned it as part of the "describe what you've tried" requirements of a question so that people don't waste their time exploring things you've already tried.

Comment: sorry about not having more detail Raymond, I've now added it above.  The point I was trying to make was the one line of code that I originally had in place is no longer working - everything else around it seems to be ok.  I get that there is a new DOM and that the old method is no longer supported - this was a great lead - but I'm still searching for a working equivalent to the original line code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The documentation for `document.selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx) says right at the top:

> selection is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use getSelection. For info, see Compatibility changes.

Change `document.selection.createRange().text` to `document.getSelection()`.

The problem was exactly what I predicted. You are calling `createRange()` on a null or undefined reference. Specifically, `document.selection` is undefined. The error message said exactly what was wrong.

Comment: Thanks Raymond but this doesn't see to do the trick either.  I've updated the original question with additional code

Comment: You didn't follow my recommendation. You didn't just change document.selection.createRange().text to document.getSelection(). You also deleted window.external.menuArguments. Put that back.

Comment: Bingo:   window.external.menuArguments.document.getSelection(); worked perfectly  - thanks so much for your help and for awiebe`s help too

Answer (score 0):

That's really not very much context, but generically, your error message means you have failed to do this:

```
var SelectedData;
var selection = window.external.menuArguments.document.selection;
if(selection != null)
{
  SelectedData = selection.createRange().text;
}
```

When you tried to get the selection, no selection had been made, hence the selection was null.  When an object is null you cannot query it, because the structure containing the information you need does not exist.

Comment: Thanks - while that is a good point it is not the problem.  For greater context I am selecting the text, and I am invoking this thru a context menu - as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853(v=vs.85).aspx  the above code has been working well for a few years now, it is however now throwing this error under windows 8.1 - IE 11.   Also, I have tried disabling Protection mode - with it enabled I don't see anything happening, with it disabled I get a pop-up error that say "Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: The member "external" is no longer part of "window".  You will have to rewrite your code according to the new DOM, rather than the legacy one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: According to that article I should be able to use window.getselection()  however var selObj = window.getselection(); also returns an error - Object doesn't support property or method getselection ??  Any further insights would be helpful

Comment: Your extension runs in its own web page, so it has a separate window context. Your `window` does not refer to the original window.

Answer (score 0):

For this adjustment, you can find:

```
b=document.selection.getSelection()
```

Or something like it
Then you can chance it using this code below:

```
b=typeof document.selection!=="undefined"?document.selection.getSelection():null
```