# Issue with createRange() method in javascript in IE11

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-11

In IE11,createRange() method throws following error:
"Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference".
I called createRange() method as follows:
this._document.selection.**createRange();**

I tried with window.getSelection() but this is also not working for me.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced lots of issues with IE and text range selection and manipulation.  I highly recommend this cross-browser JavaScript range and selection library named, appropriately, **rangy**:

https://code.google.com/p/rangy/

It will handle the obscure edge cases and it works with IE, as well as all other browsers.

Have you looked at this other StackOverflow question and accepted answer?

[Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748500/unable-to-get-property-createrange-of-undefined-or-null-reference)

Comment: yes,i first looked into the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748500/unable-to-get-property-createrange-of-undefined-or-null-reference link but this is not working  for me. In my project,i am bound to not use any external js library. Kindly provide some other solution.

Comment: Are you operating on iframes?  Why do you use `this._document.selection` instead of `window.document.selection`?  You are right to try `window.getSelection()` as a backup to `window.document.selection`.  Perhaps you need to retrieve the selection from the document's `.contentDocument` or `.contentWindow.document` or `.ownerDocument` if you are dealing with iframes.