# ComboBox throws an error:Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the ComboBox from the Ajax Control Toolkit. All the following codes were generated by VisualStudio 2013 (using asp.net 4.5). I only chose the data connection. Why am I getting this JavaScript error:"Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference" and how to fix the problem? Thank you.

```
 <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="Append" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_countries" DataTextField="country" 
     DataValueField="ID_country" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" MaxLength="0" 
      style="display: inline;">
 </asp:ComboBox>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_countries" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID_country], [country] FROM [countries] 
    ORDER BY [country]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please share the JavaScript code. Where you're calling it.

Comment: The Javascript is provided by the ASP.NET ComboBox control that comes with ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit. The asp:ScriptManager is calling the JavaScript code so basically I only provide the database connection......

Comment: This is the source of the error:  var userRange = document.selection.createRange(). Only Explorer 11 throws an error on execution of the code. No error with Safari. Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was solved, by setting the following Meta Key:

> `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,chrome=1" />`

Answer (score 1):

asp:ComboBox calls the following javascript line:

```
document.selection.createRange();
```

As you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748500/unable-to-get-property-createrange-of-undefined-or-null-reference), `document.selection` is simply not supported in IE11.

Unfortunately, you can't change ComboBox to use `document.getSelection()` instead of `document.selection.createRange()`.

**Having said that, what is there to do?**

☞ It seems that the only option is to replace the asp:ComboBox with a regular drop-down. (Or, if you need to allow user-typed input, find/implement something similar.)

Comment: there's a new version of the ACT that might address this issue?

Comment: @PTansey not that I know of.

Comment: You're correct, yehuda. It's entirely an IE11 issue.